# BASH Increment MAC Address

Tags: bash, macos, hex, decimal

I've got a valid mac address in a var called `oldMAC`
I need to increment this and then return a new valid MAC Address.

In this example I'm incrementing by 1, but it could be by any value.

So far I've got the following:

```
echo $oldMAC
mac=$(echo $oldMAC |  tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' | tr -d ':') # upper case and remove :
echo $mac

macdec=$( printf '%d\n' 0x$mac ) # convert to decimal
echo $macdec

macadd=$( expr $macdec + 1 ) # add 1
echo $macadd

machex=$( printf '%X\n' $macadd ) # convert to hex
echo $machex
```

This outputs:

```
00:12:34:ae:BC:EF (oldMAC)
001234AEBCEF (mac)
78193278191 (macdec)
78193278192 (madadd)
1234AEBCF0 (machex)
```

The issue I have is working out how to convert `1234AEBCF0` so it returns as `00:12:34:AE:BC:F0`

Can anyone advise how to do this... or is there a better way ?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend not to create own addresses in the range reserved for manufacturers.

Comment: Hi. The above is an example and I will be using a range that I'm advised is open to be used.

Comment: Remove colons`mac=${oldMAC//:}`, uppercase the string: `mac=${mac^^}`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` to rescue:

```
macnew=$(echo $machex | sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//')
```

The pattern is

```
+------------ substitute
|  +--------- any two characters
|  | +------- with the whole match
|  | |+------ and :
|  | || +---- all occurrences, utilizing the fact it means non-overlapping
|  | || |+------- another command
|  | || ||+------ substitute
|  | || ||  +---- :
|  | || ||  |+--- at the end of line
|  | || ||  || +- with nothing to get rid of the trailing :
V  V VV VV  VV V
s/../&:/g;s/:$//
```

---

You also need to make sure 12 digits are actually printed. The `printf` command can do that, just make the pattern `"%012x"`—`0` means pad with `0`s (instead of spaces) and `12` is the minimum width. Use uppercase `X` for uppercase hex digits and lowercase `x` for lowercase hex digits.

---

You can simplify the addition a bit by using the bash's built-in arithmetic expansion, which understand hexadecimal output directly, and understands both upper and lowercase, so you only need to drop the `:`s:

```
mac=$(echo $oldMAC | tr -d ':')
macadd=$(( 0x$mac + 1 ))
```

It still comes back as decimal, so you still need the printf "%012x" to convert it. You can pipe it directly to the sed to keep it short.

```
macnew=$(printf "%012x" $macadd | sed 's/../&:/g;s/:$//')
```

Comment: Thanks - This sort of works, but returns `12:34:ae:bc:f0` not `00:12:34:ae:bc:f0` How do I sort that ?

Comment: @Tom, oh, right, I missed that. You need to tell the printf to zero-pad it to 12 digits, which is done by using `%012x` as the specifier (`0` means zero-pad and 12 is requested width)

Answer (score 1):

Just need to change 2 lines.

> mac=$(echo $oldMAC |  tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' | tr -d ':')

to

```
 mac=$(echo $oldMAC | sed s/":"//g)
```

and then

> machex=$( printf '%X\n' $macadd )

to

```
machex=$( printf '%X\n' $macadd |tee|tr A-Z a-z)
```

overall

```
mac=$(echo $oldMAC|sed s/":"//g)
macdec=$(printf '%d\n' 0x$oldmac)
macadd=$(expr $macdec + 1)
machex=$( printf '%X\n' $macadd |tee|tr A-Z a-z)
```